# IIS Express unable to launch, already commented out application.host

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware, iis-express

I have found several sites and forums discussing IIS Express errors, but am having a hard time finding one specific to the issue I am having. I am running VMWare 8 with Windows Server 2008--my laptop is running Windows 7 Professional. I have already tried commenting out the HttpLogging components--as mentioned in a few posts on here--but am still receiving the error message below. I hope I am providing enough information, I will be more than happy to elaborate on anything as I have been unable to fix this problem for a few days. Here is the error I am receiving when I try to start IIS Express from the console:

[image]

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. It failed when trying to preload .NET 4.0 (the third line of your screen capture). Do you have .NET 4 installed in your VM?

Comment: I do, I have the Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. Hopefully that should be the right one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I had the client version of .NET rather than the actual framework. Details!